# Does Allah do things in succession?

Tags: fiqh, tafseer, aqidah

I have two questions here even though the title states one.

Does Allah do things in succession one after another? For example, we know the day of judgement will happen, and Allah will punish people. At the moment there is no day of judgement. So what do we make of this considering Allah is beyond time and space? Does succession imply time?

Any scholarly sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In Islamic theology, Allah (God) is believed to be beyond time and space, as He is described as eternal and not bound by the limitations of the created universe. Allah is often described as being outside of our understanding of time and space, as He is the Creator of these dimensions and not subject to them.

In discussing concepts like the Day of Judgment, scholars have explored the idea of how these events relate to Allah's eternal nature. Here are some key points to consider:

**Allah's Knowledge:** Allah is believed to have complete knowledge of past, present, and future. This means that while He is not bound by time, He knows everything that has happened, is happening, and will happen.

**Sequential Events for Human Understanding:** The concept of events happening in succession is often used in religious texts and teachings to help humans understand complex concepts. For example, the Day of Judgment is described as an event that will occur in the future, but this is a way for humans to conceptualize the idea. In reality, Allah's knowledge encompasses all events simultaneously.

**Time as a Creation:** In Islamic belief, time itself is considered a creation of Allah. He is not subject to the limitations of time and space because He is the Creator of these dimensions. Therefore, the concept of succession does not imply time as we understand it in the case of Allah.

It's important to note that discussions about Allah's attributes and nature can be complex, and different scholars may have varying interpretations and perspectives on these matters. Therefore, it's valuable to study multiple sources and consult with knowledgeable scholars to gain a comprehensive understanding of these theological concepts.